# Handle access token storage in Expo React Native app

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I am making an expo application that has some user authentication features and I am trying to find a way to **store the access token persistently**. I have come across some library such as [Asyncstorage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/) and [expo-secure-store](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/). But I have some concerned about choosing between each of these two.

- **Asyncstorage** --> I understand that it is an unencrypted, persistent data so I believe it means that if I want to store the token here securely, I should encrypt the token with some encryption method before store it into the storage.
- **expo-secure-store** --> I take it that it stores that data in an encrypted way which make it more secure than bare Asyncstorage.

However, in my application, I also planned to use Redux for state management and I thinks that Asyncstorage might work with it. Based on this, should I use Asyncstorage to store my tokens or should I use both of them for different purposes or do you guys have any idea on how this will works out? Thanks!